# Groovy rest client without libraries

Tags: rest, url, groovy

I am using a rest client to do Post

My code is

```
def postRequest() {
    def message  = "{ \"fields\": { \"project\": { \"id\": \"001\" },\"summary\": \"Test Issue For Jira Integration\",\"description\": \"Creating of an issue for for projects and issue types using the REST API\",       \"issuetype\": {          \"id\": \"5\"       }   }}"

    // POST
    def post = new URL("https://jira/rest/api/latest/issue").openConnection();
    //def message = '{"message":"this is a message"}'
    post.setRequestMethod("POST")
    String userpass = "user:pass" ;
    String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(userpass.getBytes()));
    post.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
    post.setDoOutput(true)
    post.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
    post.getOutputStream().write(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    def postRC = post.getResponseCode();
    println(postRC);
    if(postRC.equals(201)) {
        println(post.getInputStream().getText());
    }else
    {
        println(post.getInputStream().getText());
        print(postRC)
    }

}
```

I am getting 400 error code , where its getting wrong

I am successfully able to do the get request with URL

Comment: N.B I dont have option to use external libraries

Comment: 400 = bad request. it means server tried to validate your data and it's wrong. usually this response contains body with explanation - what's wrong...

Comment: also if you have 400+ status - usually response is coming through `post.getErrorStream()`

Comment: + better to build message with maps and then format it to json using JsonBuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to certificate , I have to bypass the certificate validation and its working fine. Since both the application are under same network and behind same company's firewall , I have bypass the certificate validations.

Adding the skipping certificate validation part to the above code is working for me

Answer (score 1):

400 = bad request.

it means server tried to validate your post data and it's wrong.

usually this response contains body with explanation...

for 400+ status codes the body comes through `getErrorStream()` and not through `getInputStream()`

So, I would do it like this:

```
def postRequest(url, message) {
    def post = new URL(url).openConnection();
    //def message = '{"message":"this is a message"}'
    post.setRequestMethod("POST")
    String userpass = "user:pass" ;
    String basicAuth = "Basic " + userpass.getBytes("UTF-8").encodeBase64()
    post.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
    post.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
    post.setDoOutput(true)
    if( !(message instanceof String) )message = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(message).toPrettyString()
    post.getOutputStream().write(message.getBytes("UTF-8"))
    
    def response=[:]
    response.code = post.getResponseCode()
    response.message = post.getResponseMessage()
    if( response.code>=400 ){
        try{
            response.body = post.getErrorStream()?.getText("UTF-8")
        }catch(e){}
    }else{
        response.body = post.getInputStream()?.getText("UTF-8")
    }
    assert response.code in [200,201] : "http call failure ${response.code}: ${ response.body ?: response.message }"
    return response
}

def msg = [
    fields: [
        project     : [ id: "001" ],
        summary     : "Test Issue For Jira Integration",
        description : "Creating of an issue for for projects and issue types using the REST API",
        issuetype   : [ id: "5" ]
    ]
]

def r = postRequest("http://httpbin.org/post", msg)

println r
```